# Laravel/PHP dd() displays non-structured arrays in Chrome developer tools

Tags: php, google-chrome-devtools, dd

I have noticed that writing in Laravel's Controller:

```
dd($array)
```

outputs an un-structured view of array in Chrome Developer Tools (chome 61.0.3163.91 64-bit, MAC OS).

[image]

before it was something like this (at least it seems to me that it was like this): 
[image]

Do I have 'false memories'?

OR, if dd() really outputted structured arrays in devtools, how do I bring it back?

Comment: The response tab should do a better job

Comment: just install json view plugin.

Comment: Sounds like a bug. See if it's fixed in Chrome Canary, otherwise look for existing reports on https://crbug.com or submit a new one if you can provide an easily reproducible test URL.

Comment: response tab: http://joxi.ru/nAyzY10IYB58Xr

Comment: You do not have 'false memories' :) I use this all the time. I hope this get fixed really soon...

Answer (score 0):

I've posted the same question in official chrome bugs forum https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=767386#c5
they said that it'd be corrected in Chrome 62 released on 17-OCT-2017, which is... TODAY:)

Answer (score 0):

I'm using Chrome Version 63.0.3239.132 (Official Build) (64-bit) and still have the issue.

**[Workaround until the bug is fixed.](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/24688#issuecomment-342644254)**

```
http_response_code(500);
dd('foo');
```

**Turn it into a [helper function](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/general-discussion/best-practices-for-custom-helpers-on-laravel-5/replies/28978) `ddd`**

1) Create a file called `helpers.php` in `app/Http`

2) Past the following in:

```
<?php 

function ddd(...$args){
    http_response_code(500);
    call_user_func_array('dd', $args);
}
```

3) In `composer.json`, in the `autoload` section, add `"files": ["app/Http/helpers.php"]`

4) Run `composer dump-autoload` command in terminal

Comment: For me it´s the same result